# How do I make a button pick out a different random string of text in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code in my viewcontroller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()            
        let names = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4"]
        let randomName = names.randomElement()!
        self.Label.text=randomName;
    }
}
```

How can I make the button "button", when pressed, make the label a different random item from the array "names"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `names` an instance level property (rather then been declared locally to `viewDidLoad`)

Create a "interface builder action function", wire this to your button in the story board.

In this action function, simply pick a random word and assign it to the label.

For example...

```
let names = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4"]

//...

@IBAction
func pickRandomWord(_ sender: Any) {
    let randomName = names.randomElement()!
    self.Label.text=randomName;
}
```

Comment: Odds are about 1 out of 4 it will repeat the last value

Comment: @LeoDabus Sure, and if that's important, you would have a secondary cache, where you would remove the value as it's used - I was focused on the need to make the operation work in a button ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it programmatically, you can check addTarget()
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618259-addtarget